# Add text to paragraph in InDesign with script?

Tags: adobe-indesign

There's a particular paragraph in my document and I want to add new content programatically. Is there any function to do this? I need something like this:

app.activeDocument.stories[7].paragraphs[0].contents.insertAfter = "H mmmb vf  vvcc vv\r";

Comment: I think we need a bit more information to understand why you want to do it like this. I'm just wondering why you don't just add the content manually or use find/replace?